# How to get pod labels overwritten in GitLab Kubernetes executor/runner?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab runner with this configuration:

```
runners:
  privileged: false
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "managed-ng-1"
        pod_labels_overwrite_allowed = ".*"

        [runners.kubernetes.pod_labels]
          "kubernetes.io/arch" = "amd64"
          "job_id" = "${CI_JOB_ID}"
          "job_name" = "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
          "pipeline_id" = "${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
          "project" = "${CI_PROJECT_PATH}"
```

I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with this `variables` section:

```
variables:
  KUBERNETES_POD_LABELS_1: "karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-local-nvme=256G"
  KUBERNETES_POD_LABELS_2: "kubernetes.io/arch=arm64"
```

When the job runs, the logs show this:

```
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
"PodLabels" "karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-local-nvme" overwritten with "256G"
"PodLabels" "kubernetes.io/arch" overwritten with "arm64"
```

However, if I run `kubectl describe pod` against the pod, these labels are not there:

```
Labels:       job_id=297
              job_name=job1
              kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
              pipeline_id=116
              pod=runner-awq3dkxf-project-5-concurrent-0
              project=root_simple-cicd-test
```

I explicitly added a default value for "kubernetes.io/arch" in case the label overwriting mechanism only worked if there was already a label with a value.

I don't know why this isn't working. Are there any other logs I should be looking at that might explain what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check these [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71326326/19230181)
[Link2](https://werf.io/documentation/v1.2/advanced/ci_cd/run_in_container/use_gitlab_ci_cd_with_kubernetes_executor.html) might help you in finding solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug in the Kubernetes executor: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29168